# is It possible to find the undefined state of an array using Jquery method "inArray"

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am finding an array exist or not, if that's not exist then it became `undefined` using the if condition, but is it possible to find the same using the jquery's inbuild method "inArray"..

my try:

it works fine:

```
var group = [];

if(group[i % 3] === undefined){
        group[i % 3] = $("<fieldset />");
    }
```

but using jquery method i am not get the proper result:

```
if($.inArray(group[i % 3], []) < 0){
        group[i % 3] = $("<fieldset />");
    }
```

any one give me a correct suggestion to use the jquery method to find a array as "undefined"?

Comment: What's wrong with using vanilla JS?

Comment: no issues, but i like to use the jQuery methods, since i am using the codes for multiple browsers, devices..

Comment: Yes, but the first way is cross-browser. jQuery is not the magical solution to everything and you don't need to replace all your vanilla JS with it.

Comment: thanks. let me do. But still what is the answer for my question(as a information)?

Comment: Your non-jQuery code is much better than any possible jQuery version. This particular jQuery code doesn't make much sense, even if you change the second `inArray` argument from `[]` to `group` as in acudar's answer. Why do you want to *search* the array? Your non-jQuery code doesn't search the array, it just checks the specific element. Were you looking for jQuery code that does the same thing as your non-jQuery code? Why? It will just be worse code. This is not what jQuery is made for.

Comment: Got a valid points. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($.inArray(group[i % 3], group ) === undefined ){
        group[i % 3] = $("<fieldset />");
    }
```

Comment: try comparing to **-1** as well